# FireBase data download during app launch

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have integrated with FireBase database and I'm supporting offline mode. I'm also listening to certain parts of the JSON tree for new additions, changes and removal.

When my app launches I'm configuring the database and enabling offline mode as required before I create any references to the database.

```
[FIRApp configure];

[FIRDatabase database].persistenceEnabled = YES;
```

Everything works fine except that every time I quit my app and relaunch it, the entire contents of the JSON tree that I'm listening to gets downloaded.

Downloading this content every time during app re-launch will consume all the download bandwidth provided in each tier. You can't expect users to keep the app running all the time.

Why are the listeners downloading everything even when there has been no change ? Is there an alternate solution ?

Comment: If the data hasn't changed, we should download almost nothing.  If the data is large and there are only small changes, you should download only sections that have changes.  If the data is small or it's large but has a lot of changes, you may see the entire thing be re-downloaded.

If you're pretty sure it's downloading more than it should, can you enable logging with [[FIRDatabase database].setLoggingEnabled:YES], run the app twice in a row, and email the output to me (mikelehen@google.com)?  Thanks!

Comment: Done. I have captured the logs and sent them to you. Thanks for looking into this.

Comment: I have been able to duplicate this behavior even with a small data set on the device and simulator.

Comment: I'm using FB via cocoa pods and I sync to this list  'Firebase/Core', 'Firebase/Database', 'Firebase/Auth'

Comment: Per our email thread, it's expected to get ChildAdded events for the data you're syncing every time you run the app.  You can potentially use queries to limit the data you're syncing / listening to "new" data for some definition of "new" as appropriate for your use case.